# VS 2019 Copy File to Another Location After Save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am wondering what would be the best way to copy an item in a VS project/solution to another local directory after the file has been saved. Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this automatically. In other words, once the file is saved in the project/solution, it will automatically copy the file, and replace if already exists, to the other directory location.

Is there a solution for this that already exists? What would I need to do to accomplish this, if not?

Please, let me know if further clarification is required.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example extension](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnDocumentSaved) that subscribes to DocumentSaved event in VS. You can change it to copy the file to another location.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. I need to save the file normally and save a copy to another location at the same time. This extension is intriguing though. Thanks!

Comment: @mappingman subscribing to DocumentSaved preserves normal file save.